# Equivalent of Set Inverse in ChildOf constraint

Tags: transforms, constraints

I have an object, A, with ChildOf constraint whose target is B, *Set Inverse* is applied to keep A's transformation. In the middle of the animation, I needed to disable this constraint( B is transformed without affecting A) and enable it again much later. When enabling the constraint again, A's transform should be also be kept but *Set Inverse* is not an option because it would ruin the initial setup. So I guess I have to set the object's matrix via console but don't know how, any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use more than one Child Of constraint - with each set to a different 'inverse'. Then use the Influence to blend in each at the appropriate point in the animation - rather than re-using the same one.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing but the more actions I make, the more childof constraints I need. That is why I'm looking for a workaround without needing redundant constraints.

Comment: You could potentially trigger the Set Inverse via Python and trigger it from a handler on change of frame - but that would likely be more complicated than simply using multiple constraints. Multiple constraints have very little overhead - the only downside would be how cumbersome it could be to manage many, but careful naming of the constraints and possibly using Drivers to automatically adjust the influence could help there.